# How do I perform MDX member subtraction across another hierarchy?

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx

I have a cube with customers and products. Each customer holds a varying combination of products, each in different amounts.

I would like to calculate the difference (subtraction), between one customer and another, of amounts held in each product.

I am using SQL Server Analysis Services 2014. An example from AdventureWorksDW2014 would be:

```
select
{[Customer].[Country].&[Australia],[Customer].[Country].&[Canada]} on columns,
non empty ([Product].[Category].members, [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]) on rows
from 
[Adventure Works]
```

This generates the following output:

```
                Australia       Canada
All Products    $9,061,000.58   $1,977,844.86
Accessories     $138,690.63     $103,377.85
Bikes           $8,852,050.00   $1,821,302.39
Clothing        $70,259.95      $53,164.62
```

However what I would like to obtain is

```
                Australia       Canada          (Australia - Canada)
All Products    $9,061,000.58   $1,977,844.86   $7,083,155.72
Accessories     $138,690.63     $103,377.85     $35,312.78
Bikes           $8,852,050.00   $1,821,302.39   $7,030,747.61
Clothing        $70,259.95      $53,164.62      $17,095.33
```

Ideally this could be performed not just in MDX, but allowing the user to select any two arbitrary customers for comparison.

This is my first MDX question, so please let me know if it should be framed differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the MDX query for the desired output:

```
WITH MEMBER Australia AS
SUM({([Measures].[Internet Sales Amount], [Customer].[Country].&[Australia])}), FORMAT_STRING = "#,#.##"
MEMBER Canada AS
SUM({([Measures].[Internet Sales Amount], [Customer].[Country].&[Canada])}), FORMAT_STRING = "#,#.##"
MEMBER [Australia - Canada] AS
[Australia] - [Canada]
SELECT
{[Australia], [Canada], [Australia - Canada]} ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY {[Product].[Category].MEMBERS} ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works]
```

Comment: Thanks very much, this generates the correct output.

How should I design my cube to allow users to select any arbitrary combination of countries? Do I need two separate country dimensions, CountriesDim1 and CountriesDim2, then the user can add both?

Comment: Try marking this as an answer and open a new question. This answer has done its job.

Comment: Thanks, marked as answered, I will open a separate question about how to make this work over many different combinations.